# how to add Jquery slideDown alert at php error

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my code bootstrap alert is showing without any effect. I want to add jquery `slideDown` effect to error.

Error occurs when a user enters wrong credentials to log in. 
The server-side language is PHP

Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $uname=$_POST['user'];
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $query="select * from login_info where user_name = '$uname' AND password='$user_pass'";

    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("error");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){
            $_SESSION['user_name']=$uname;
          echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo '

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" aria-label="close"></a>
            <strong>Error!</strong> Email OR Password is incorrect.
            <a href="#" class="close" id="btn">&times;</a>
        </div>

                '
            ;
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you reaching this script that is executing?

Comment: @Taplar  Script is working and error showing but no effect. I want to add `slideDown` effect on showing

Comment: Are you getting to this logic via a page transfer, or are you using an ajax request to get to this logic?

Comment: @Taplar Dont know about Ajax.  simply using php. Whole code of php is written above